# Remove all from the last element to the end of a div (preferably via JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to create a button which are going to remove all the text from the last element to the end of a div.

Please find below my code.
**HTML**

```
<button id="clearLastLine">Clear Last Line</button>
</br>
<div class="parent">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3 </p> <br>Item 4
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#clearLastLine").on('click', function() {
  $(".parent").children().last().remove();
});
```

Please note that with my code I cannot remove the text which is outside of the elements such as break or after paragraph.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's still unclear what you expect from your code: do you mean you want to remove `<p>Item 3</p>`? Or just `Item 4`? Or `<br>Item 4`? Last element is a little ambiguous here.

Comment: Please explain your code properly so that others don't have to spend much time understanding your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want to remove the `Item 4` node from the DOM, you simply need to change `children()` to `contents()`:

```js
$("#clearLastLine").on('click', function() {
  $(".parent").contents().last().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clearLastLine">Clear Last Line</button><br />
<div class="parent">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3 </p> <br />Item 4
</div>
```

Comment: Why its deleting on 2nd click?

Comment: Because it removes the last item within `#clearLastLine` every time you trigger the event. If you only want to do it once, use `one()` instead of `on()`

Comment: I guess user needs to remove it at once not on clicking multiple times

Comment: It does that for me. Does it not remove the `Item 4` text for you on first click?

Comment: I'm talking about other elements

Comment: I think the confusion lies in that subsequent clicks will seemingly remove nothing. In actual fact, they are removing text nodes containing only white space between elements.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're saying. In that case, @Justastudent is correct. The clicks that appear to do nothing are because the empty nodes between the `p` elements are being removed.